# How to store image from camera in SQLiteDatabase and show preview In Android Application?

Tags: android, database, image

I want to store image from camera in android application . I want to know want datatype I should use . Is I need to store image in application folder ? I want to know How to store image to drawable_mdpi. I am new in Android . So I want to see complete answer with code sample.After store image , I want to view images from database with gallery.

Comment: Simple Docs: [Little Complex](http://www.anddev.org/png_image_--und-gt_sqlite_db_--und-gt_imageview-t7188.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well You have to store the image in the form of `byte[]` into the database `SQLite`. Once you have captured image You can have it `byte[]` and then you can store them onto the database and one you stored them onto the database you can also retrieve a `byte[]` from database and then once you get `byte[]` from database you can decode the `byte[]` into `bitmap`.

Hope this guide helps?

http://sree.cc/google/storing-and-retriving-images-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Regards
sHaH

Comment: did this helped buddy ?? u tried it??? its a perfect example to read and write image into SQlite Databases

Comment: No.I don't want to get image from connection . I get images from Android Camera.

Comment: Yes fine just leave the code which is getting image from connection. DO u want that as well that how to capture image from CAmera????